# Unreal Engine How would I make a one way physics door, that takes both walking into it, and mouse move it

Tags: physics, game-mechanics, unreal-4, first-person-shooter

Horror game.
In the bathroom stalls I want the doors that

- opens 45 degrees
- you can walk into to open it
- or slowly use the mouse to open it while standing still
- and "lock" it, once inside the stall

I cannot find this in any tutorial.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried to solve each of those four sub-problems individually and then to connect the solutions you found? Where exactly did you get stuck?